# Caesar Decipher function alternative C++

Tags: c++, caesar-cipher

Hi I'm working on this Caesar cipher decrytor that take encrypted strings and decipher them with all keys (and then another function will match them up if they are similar to another message). I have the the Decipher function but I was just wondering if there's any other way I could write the function. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

```
void Decipher(char cip[], char key){

for(int i = 0; cip[i] != '\0'; i++){
  if(cip[i] == ' '){
      cip[i]= cip[i];

  }else if(int(cip[i] >= int(key){
      cip[i] = char(int(cip[i]) - ((int(key) - 65) % 26));

  }else{
        cip[i] = char(26 + int(cip[i]) - ((int(key)-65) % 26);
  }

 }

}
```

Comment: Yes, use character constants, such as 'A' instead of the number 65.

Answer (score 1):

There's *always* another way. Usually a half dozen more ways. First, I'd move the part that does the decryption proper into a function by itself.

```
char decipher(char in, char key) { 
    // ..
    return in;
}
```

Then given the amount of commonality in your code, I'd try to remove at least some of the repetition:

```
char decipher(char in, char key) {
    if (in != ' ') {
        in = char(in - ((key - 'A') % 26));
        if (in < 0) 
            in += 26;
    }
    return in;
}
```

That leaves us the outer routine that steps through the string and deciphers each element. I'd probably use a standard algorithm for that and a reference to an `std::string` as the parameter):

```
void decipher(std::string &s, char key) { 
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), 
        [key](char c) { return decipher(c, key); });
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a range-based `for` loop instead of `transform`:

```
for (auto &c : s) 
     c = decipher(c, key);
```

Comment: This is an assignment and Im only allowed to use that one decipher function not two with the (char cip[], char key) parameters. Anyway you can adapt that so I still has one function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want proper C++(11) then...

```
void Decipher(std::string& cip, unsigned char key) {
    for (auto&& c : cip) {
        if (c == ' ')
            continue;
        if (((unsigned char)c) >= key)
            c = (char)(((int)c) - (((int)key) - 'A') % 26);
        else
            c = (char)(26 + ((int)c) - ((((int)key) - 'A') % 26));
    }
}
```

This takes a string as a reference and then uses a range-based for loop to iterate over the the chars in the string taking an r-value reference in order to make changes to the char affect the original string.

I haven't made any changes to how you perform the rotation math since that's not something relevant to how *C++ish* it is.